# Pythonic way to convert list of signed int32 to binary/boolean numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there any better (more efficient and/or readable) way to convert signed int32 to transposed binary/boolean numpy array?

> This example is a simplification. `fp` can have almost 1,000 elements

This is what I have so far (using Python 2.7):

```
fp = [-15707075, -284140225]
np.transpose(np.array([[b == '1' for b in list('{:32b}'.format(i & 0xffffffff))] for i in fp]))
```

Result:

```
[[ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [ True False]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]
 [False  True]
 [ True  True]
 [False False]
 [False  True]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [False  True]
 [ True  True]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`numpy.unpackbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html) is faster if `fp` is a large NumPy array:

```
(np.unpackbits(fp.astype('>i4').view('4,uint8'), axis=1).T.astype(bool))
```

`astype('>i4')` converts `fp` to an array of big-endian 32-bit ints, then
`view('4,uint8')` views (or, perhaps you might say re-interprets) the 32-bit
ints as four 8-bit ints.  This is done since `unpackbits` expects an array of
unsigned 8-bit ints. Big-endian format is used to ensure the most significant
bits are on the left -- this arranges the values so `np.unpackbits` returns the
bits in the desired order.

```
In [280]: fp = np.array([-15707075, -284140225])

In [281]: fp.astype('>i4').view('4,uint8')
Out[281]: 
array([[255,  16,  84,  61],
       [239,  16,  93,  63]], dtype=uint8)

In [282]: np.unpackbits(fp.astype('>i4').view('4,uint8'), axis=1)
Out[282]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

```
import numpy as np

fp = np.array([-15707075, -284140225])
expected = (np.transpose(np.array([[b == '1' for b in list('{:32b}'.format(i & 0xffffffff))] for i in fp])))

result = (np.unpackbits(fp.astype('>i4').view('4,uint8'), axis=1).T.astype(bool))

assert (expected == result).all()
```

---

Using `np.unpackbits` is about 72x faster (on my machine) for an array of size 100. The speed
advantage increases with the length of `fp`:

```
In [241]: fp = np.random.random(size=100).view('int32')

In [276]: %timeit expected = (np.transpose(np.array([[b == '1' for b in list('{:32b}'.format(i & 0xffffffff))] for i in fp])))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.22 ms per loop

In [277]: %timeit result = (np.unpackbits(fp.astype('>i4').view('4,uint8'), axis=1).T.astype(bool))
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: Great. +1 for the explanation and considering large `fp`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not *much* better, but still more Pythonic:

```
np.array([list('{:32b}'.format(i & 0xffffffff)) for i in fp]).astype(bool).T
```